# Resulting Ambiguous Type Variable in Persistent's `get` call

Tags: haskell, monads, yesod, persistent

I'm having the following error while trying to retrieve a list of Entities from a list of foreign attributes.

```
Handler/ContactList.hs:21:57:
Couldn't match type `PersistMonadBackend m0'
              with `persistent-1.3.0.6:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.SqlBackend'
The type variable `m0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type sig`enter code here`nature that fixes these type variable(s)
Expected type: PersistEntityBackend User
  Actual type: PersistMonadBackend m0
In the expression: `enter code here`get
In the expression: (get $ ((contactContact val) :: UserId))
In the first argument of `map', namely
  `(\ (Entity key val) -> (get $ ((contactContact val) :: UserId)))'
```

The code below gets a List entity which has a one-to-many relationship with contact. In the Contact Model, there is an attribute called contact to represent the foreign key constraint to User (The type for conctact is UserId). 
I'm Trying to retrieve the list of contacts (list of userIds) and perform a map get to retrieve the list of user entities.

For my understanding, there is a problem of type generalization while using get on a Contact Entity with UserId type, but I can't figure out what is the proper type it can work with.

```
getContactsR :: Handler Html
getContactsR  = do
  muser <- maybeAuth
  case muser of 
    Just (Entity userId user) -> do
      (list, contacts) <- runDB $ do 
          maybeList <- getBy (UniqueList userId)
          case maybeList of
            Just (Entity listId list) -> do
              contacts' <- selectList [ContactList ==. listId] []                        
              let contacts = map (\(Entity key val) -> (get $ ((contactContact val) :: UserId) )) contacts'
              return (list, contacts')
           Nothing -> error "Could not retrieve contact list"
      defaultLayout $(widgetFile "contacts")
    Nothing -> do
     setMessage $ toHtml ("Error getting contact list"  :: Text)
     redirect HomeR
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to replace:

```
let contacts = map (\(Entity key val) -> (get $ ((contactContact val) :: UserId) )) contacts'
```

with:

```
contacts <- mapM (\(Entity key val) -> (get $ ((contactContact val) :: UserId) )) contacts'
```

(Yes, the Persistent error messages here are terrible, we're working on that for Persistent 2.0.) I think the `UserId` type annotation may not even be necessary.